# Just beginning C++ in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, build-process

...and I mean LITERALLY just beginning. As in, I just started earlier today.

All I want to do is figure out how to build and run a 'hello_world' code from my textbook, but the 'build and run' button will not light up. I have read through 'Xcode Features Overview' as well as checking out at some help forums, and it's clear that I need files in my template that I just don't have. I think the issue is that I'm starting with a blank template when I should be starting with a 'C++ tool' template. This seems like it should be incredibly simple, but when I hit file/New Project... assistant does not pop up, instead I get a window with very limited options including Application, Framework & Library, Application Plug-in, System Plug-in and Other. I feel like I can pick a lot of this up from help forums and reference documents but I definitely need to figure out how to successfully build and run a program first XD

P.S. I have Xcode 3.2.2 if it makes a difference

Comment: click on "Command line tool" under the "Application" tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "New Project" window, select Application > Command Line Tool, and choose "C++ stdc++" from the Type drop down.